A SF novel where one character makes a "light portrait" of another one, with huge consequences
I read this novel so long ago I don't even remember when. Maybe 40 years ago, or more.
I'm positive it is a novel, but the only thing that comes to my mind is one small but essential episode.
One character, a woman, was a "light artist" : she used light to create 3D patterns. The SF aspect is that, like the light from the "light-sabers" in Star Wars, the light beams were of finite length, so the creations were finite size "sculptures".
The artist met another character, a man. There was some sexual tension between them. For a lot of reasons, which I don't remember precisely, there was no possibility for this tension to lead to consummation.
She offered to make a "light portrait" of the man. It was not meant to be realistic, but rather to be an abstract representation of her feelings about his personality. Most of it was very positive, except for one detail : a dark coloured (perhaps a dark purple?) spot, like a knot, at the center of the mostly bright "sculpture".
When he asked about this "dark knot", she answered that she felt that something was blocking him from realising his full potential and the knot represented this block.
IIRC, this sculpture was a turning point is the plot, as it led the man to an introspection, which in turn led to a successful effort to overcome that block with huge consequences. Alas, I don't remember any more details.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1813417.The_Rainbow_Cadenza?

At first, I thought it was going to be another Asimov short story. Where the light sculptures were Actually being done by the artist's malfunctioning robot. During a show displaying "her" works, a robot tech viewing the show, notices her malfunctioning robot, and "fixes" it for her. Thus destroying its creativity, and she in a rage/despair at the loss, kills him.

@NJohnny    Do you know the title of this story ? But mine is just a page of The Naked Sun, not a short story by itself

@Alfred It's called "Light Verse" - you can find it in the Buy Jupiter anthology.

@ClaraDíazSanchez Thanks !

This sounds very much like a vital plot point in The Naked Sun, the 1957 novel by Isaac Asimov.
The detective, Elijah Baley, is interviewing the suspect Gladia Delmarre, and she explains to him about her work sculpting "light-forms":

It’s  a kind of optical illusion, I’ve been told. We set up
force-fields at  different energy levels. They’re extrusions of
hyper-space, really,  and don’t have the properties of ordinary space
at all. Depending  on the energy level, the human eye sees light of
different shades.  The shapes and colours are controlled by the warmth
of my  fingers against appropriate spots on the pedestal.

She sculpts a portrait of him. It mainly has a blue form, representing Earth, enclosed by "a flat, lustre-
less hollow cube of slate grey", representing the way his soul was confined behind walls. On seeing the work Baley exclaims "Jehoshaphat!", and this becomes part of the work too:

Now you say “Jehoshaphat” sometimes and that’s just a little blob of
violet. A little  sharp blob because it usually comes out ping, like
that.’ And the  little blob was there, glowing just off centre.

The realization that he was enclosed in walls arising from his claustrophobia was indeed key to him solving the case.

Thanks !  My memory  incorrectly attributed the claustrophobla to the violet blob meaning "Jehosophat" and forgot the hollow cube, but yes, it was indeed The Naked Sun !

The "huge consequences" I remembered go well beyond solving the case. Now that I realise that the novel is The Naked Sun I remember that getting rid of his claustrophobia opened the way to the second, robot-free, colonisation of the galaxy. Though this may be developed only in a much later book... when Asimov decided to relate his Elijah & R. Daneel Olivaw novels to the Foundation series.

@Alfred My recollection was that it was a bit more subtle. The first aspect was that he was implicitly /challenged/ to go out into the open, which almost resulted in his assassination. The second was that he started to realise that people /didn't/ have to live in "caves of steel", and that even if he wasn't happy in the open his successors (explicitly, IIRC, his son) accompanied by robots might be.

@MarkMorganLloyd Well, yes, the actual "going in the open" (beyond the pursuit of the police investigation of this book) was in a different novel, written much later and involving his son. But the realisation that people could and should go in the open starts with the portrait. The psychological impulse to remove that ugly "flat, lustre-less hollow cube of slate grey" begins here, I strongly feel.
